# Python C API: Call a Python function with argument(s) passed by reference

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I'm writing a python module in C and I need to have it call a Python function with one of the arguments passed by "reference".  The end result should be that what the Python function does to the argument gets saved into the original C variable.

```
int      *resume;      // this int is actually passed in to this body of code
PyObject *resumeInt;   // which was originally a C callback func for libnids, but
PyObject *ret;         // I removed/rewrote most of this code for clarity

resumeInt = Py_BuildValue("i",-1);
ret = PyObject_CallFunction(tcpResumeFunc, "(O)", resumeInt);    

*resume = PyInt_AsLong(resumeInt);
Py_DECREF(ret);
Py_DECREF(resumeInt);
```

To test, I had the Python function that tcpResumeFunc represents modify the passed-in integer to = 5. When I print out *resume at the end of this code, however, it retains it's initial -1 value.  I know I am misunderstanding something about how the API works.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding something about how variables work in Python. Variables in Python do not contain values; they refer to them - like in Java, except there are no "primitives" (not even `int`). Assignment to a variable doesn't overwrite the old value; it simply causes the variable to refer to the new value and cease referring to the old one (which may then be garbage-collected if nothing else refers to it).

Why not just actually return (and use) a value (since Python functions always return something anyway, even if it's just the implicit return of `None`)?

---

Edit: Working through an example, because it's too long for a comment reply.

From C, we call PyObject_CallFunction, which hands a PyObject* over to the Python function. In Python, the function parameter (we'll call it `spam`) now refers to the pointed-at PyObject.

When we write `spam += 6` in the function, that is the same as `spam = spam + 6`. The bytecode interpreter gets the PyObject that represents the value 6, runs a special bytecode that inspects the value represented by the two objects, adds them, and creates a new PyObject (or fetches one from a cache) that represents the sum.

Then `spam` is rebound to the new object; but the `spam` variable-reference is on the Python side of the memory fence, and is not the same thing as the PyObject* on the C side of the fence.

Thus, `resumeInt` does **not** get pointed at the newly created/fetched PyObject.

It is actually behaving the exact same way as it would calling the Python function from Python. Try it:

```
def fry(spam):
  spam += 1

eggs = 3
fry(eggs)
eggs # still 3!
```

This happens because rebinding `spam` does not affect `eggs`, which is a separate variable. We are not passing by reference; we are passing **a** reference **by value**. Just like in Java.

Comment: I do understand that, (I think) I assumed that since *resumeInt referred to the same object, after passing it to PyObject_CallFunction I would be left with the new *resumeInt as modified by the Python function called.  Then I just convert it back to a C variable with PyInt_AsLong.  Is there something wrong with that idea?  Your suggestion does sound a bit more elegant and easier, but I'd like to understand this.

Comment: Ah, after your edit it makes more sense.  So what I'm trying to do would probably be impossible.  I will modify the code to have it return the value.  I'd vote up but I don't have enough reputation; great answer though, thanks a lot!