# Copying Python object types like PyInstance and PyFunction

Tags: python, c++, visual-c++

I am new to the world of Python C API.

I have been stuck at a particular scenario involving instance and function object types.
I need to deep copy both the instance and function object types.

Here, pcoOriginalValue is type PyObject*.

```
PyObject* pcoInstanceCopy;
if( true == PyInstance_Check(pcoOriginalValue))
{
  //I need to deep copy the contents of pcoOriginalValue to pcoInstanceCopy here.
}
```

Same goes for,

```
PyObject* pcoFunctionCopy;
if( true == PyFunction_Check(pcoOriginalValue))
{
  //I need to deep copy the contents of pcoOriginalValue to pcoFunctionCopy here.
}
```

Any references or pointers would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Use copy.deepcopy. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558957/how-to-call-a-python-function-by-name-from-the-c-api

Comment: @vz0, i am using Python C API. That is possible in simple python.

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that you can just simulate from the C API the call to "import copy;copy.deepcopy". Unless you want to implement the actual deep copying yourself.

Comment: Yes, looking to implement the deep copying myself.

Answer (score 0):

While you can always call [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) standard library function from your C code, it seems you want to implement the actual deep copying yourself.

My quick (and poor) comment is that you first understand how to do that in Pure Python, and then translate your code to CPython C API calls. You may use the [current copy.deepcopy implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9fc4a1ebe652/Lib/copy.py#l137) as a starting point.